# Minimalizing variable's scope in C++

Tags: c++, variables, scope

I am programming for a while now and I've started trying to improve my code. Since I really hate creating bazillion of variables that are used only once in long function, is it good practice to shorten variable scope by using brackets?
i.e.
instead writing:

```
void fcn()
{
  int var1;
  // some part of fcn
  // use of var1;
  // rest of fcn
}
```

write:

```
void fcn()
{
  // some part of fcn
  {
    int var1;
    // use of var100;
  }
  // rest of fcn
}
```

Comment: If you're anywhere near a bazillion variables in a function, you need to split that function up - you get fresh new scopes with each function. (That said, is is done for things like locks in particular.)

Comment: yes, I would rather split that piece of logic into a separate function. It is clearer to read and at the same time have minimal scope.

Comment: Don't declare variables at the top of the function as if you were a Pascal programmer. Declare as near use as possible. If you only use a variable once, do you really need it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is indeed a good idea to keep the scope of variables as tight as possible.

In your case, unless you are absolutely certain that your code using `var1` will only ever be used in `fcn` (and if my experience is anything to go by, I tend to misjudge that), you could split that code out to a separate function. Your program will scale better that way, and testing will also be simpler. Else, use scope blocks as you currently do.

Answer (score 6):

There are certainly context in which this approach is a good practice.

It is so wide spreaded around 'if/range for/while/case' statements that explicit initializer in those statement were added in C++17 and C++20.

Comment: @Bathsheba tx, I sponsor your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't write `int var1;` *anywhere*.

Firstly `var1` is a terrible name.

Secondly you now have the potential for undefined behaviour, if any code path can read `var1` before it is assigned.

Prefer

```
int meaningfulName = initialValue;
```

Or even better

```
const int meaningfulName = value;
```

Having done that, the scopes you are choosing between are more restricted. If there is still a choice, prefer the narrowest scope possible.